# What does volumes do in docker-compose

Tags: docker

I am currently learning Docker. I am stucked at the idea of volumes. I assume that they made to store the data whenever we restart the container etc., but i do not understand what happens if we don't provide the ":" for the source:target.
Example:

```
- "/usr/src/my-app/frontend/node_modules"
- "/usr/src/my-app/backend/node_modules"
```

What do we store inside the container if we use volumes like above?

The whole `docker-compose`

```
version: '3'

services:

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"


  backend:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./backend
    container_name: backend
    volumes:
      - "/usr/src/my-app/backend/node_modules"
      - "./backend:/usr/src/my-app/backend"


  frontend:
    build: 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./frontend
    container_name: frontend
    environment:
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"
    volumes:
      - "/usr/src/my-app/frontend/node_modules"
      - "./frontend:/usr/src/my-app/frontend"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an anonymous volume. It is managed by docker like a named volume, but it doesn't have a real name, only a GUID. Likewise, it's similar to the one you get when you use the [VOLUME](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume) instruction in your Dockerfile without mounting a named volume or bind mount to that path when running the container.

See this for example (emphasis mine):

> -v or --volume: Consists of three fields, separated by colon characters (:). The fields must be in the correct order, and the meaning of each field is not immediately obvious.
> In the case of named volumes, the first field is the name of the volume, and is unique on a given host machine. **For anonymous volumes, the first field is omitted**.

https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#choose-the--v-or---mount-flag

As long as you keep the container and only restart it, the same volume will be used. If you delete the container / create a new container, it will use a new volume.

Comment: so what is the source if i am omiting it?

Comment: @randomobject123, the source is the anonymous volume. If it's the first time using it, it will be empty and therefore gets populated by the content of the container. https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container